# Rendering Views from external assemblies in .NET 6 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a .NET 6 MVC Web App that references an assembly with a controller and view. I have been able to Google my way through adding reference to and calling the external controller.

Now I am stuck trying to reference the View in the assembly, as the Razor engine still expects it to exist in the main application. I saw an example for MVC6 that says to add:

```
builder.Services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
  options.FileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(
    new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        typeof(BooksController).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
        "BookStore.Portal" // your external assembly's base namespace
    ),
    options.FileProvider
  );
});
```

but 'FileProvider' is not an available property of options. Am I missing a package? Is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded via NPM? If not, You could install it by this command `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded`. If you have installed it, Have you configured it anywhere in your project? Ref: [File Providers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0#composite-file-provider)

Comment: I added the nuget package, but that didn't enable the FileProvider property. Do you have to specify every razor view you need individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at least for .NET 6 you don't have to do anything special. Just reference your Razor Class Library and you have access to it. Nothing in the Startup (now Program). I did have to structure the project in the typical 'Controllers'/'Views' folder structure, but my calling application finds the controllers and views.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution to the issue. I would suggest you accept your answer as a solution to this question after 48 hrs. It could help other community members in the future with similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: My question is in many cases, we cannot just create a " Razor Class Library" project just because we want to read .cshtml files there.  Our ultimate goal is reading .cshtml from any project types right?

Answer (score 0):

I followed the previous answer and found it, and the referenced pages, were missing key details to make it work (marking views as embedded resources and views appear to become case sensitive).

Update: You also need to replicate your `_ViewStart.cshtml` file in your library Views folder, else your asp tags may not build.

### Research steps:

1. Cloned the Microsoft [Sample app](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/mvc/advanced/app-parts/sample2) mentioned on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
2. Ran WebAppParts sample (.Net core 3.0) - Worked
3. Updated WebAppParts sample to .Net 6.0 - Worked
4. Created a brand new .Net 6 Web Application
5. Added MySharedApp .Net 6 library
6. Added Snippet to the program main setup and called this instead of `AddControllersWithViews`

   ```
   public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       var assembly = typeof(MySharedController).Assembly;
       services.AddControllersWithViews()
           .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
           .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

       services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
       { options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly)); });
   }
   ```
7. Added menu hyperlink to `MyShared/index` in _Layout.cshtml - It cannot find the view
8. Diff'ed the sample project against my new one and slowly migrated settings/changes across.
9. Added `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded` NuGet to library.
10. Found that any shared views needed to be marked as `Embedded resource` in the views `Build Action`. This was not apparent in the sample app as the view displays as `Content` in the sample app, despite this entry in the .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\MyShared\Index.cshtml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

11. After all these changes, my .Net 6.0 test web app started sharing the library's views and controller.
12. Final example below is what I reduced my app code to in `Program.Main()`. Feel free to remove the Auth or Json lines if not needed:

    ```
       var assembly = typeof(AnySharedController).Assembly;

       builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
           .AddJsonOptions(x => x.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)
           .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
           .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
           .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

       builder.Services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
       {
           options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly));
       });
    ```
13. While migrating Views to a library, I found that partial views were not found unless the view or partial view name was the same case.

e.g. This one failed

```
@(await Html.PartialAsync("titlepartial"))
```

Then this one worked

```
@(await Html.PartialAsync("TitlePartial"))
```